# iText7 pdfSweep Redacting More Than It's Supposed To

Tags: itext7

While using pdfSweep, it's redacting more text than it's supposed to. Why is it redacting "JS" as well?

[image: Original:]

[image: Redacted:]

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
    CompositeCleanupStrategy cleanupStrategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();
    cleanupStrategy.add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("032016"));
    cleanupStrategy.add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("123123123"));
    PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(cleanupStrategy);
    autoSweep.cleanUp(pdfDoc);
```

Comment: *"Why is it redacting "JS" as well?"* - most likely the font bounding box around "JS" intersects the cleanup areas determined based on the matches of the regular expressions. As you didn't share the PDF in question, I cannot be sure, though. (Indeed, the `RegexBasedCleanupStrategy` does not "redact exactly the matches of the regular expressions" but "determines areas to redact based on the matches of the regular expressions and redacts all elements intersecting these areas".)

Comment: I'm wondering if this bounding-box is an issue, I'm wondering whether I can simply change the numbers instead of redacting it, like "032016" to "******".
Will that be secure?

Comment: Replacing in generic documents is as complex as redaction.